# Is it lawful for some English NHS trusts to stock more kinds of medications than others?

Tags: england-and-wales, health

#### Factual Situation

My daughter lives in an area covered by a NHS Trust beneath that's not Oxford. Her migraine can be only treated with a triptan on Oxford's formulary, but not her own area's, like Eletriptan. His GP said that he can't prescribe her a triptan on Oxford's formulary. The only way she can get it, is if she's admitted to their ER or is eligible for Oxford NHS. But she isn't.

#### Legal Question

Isn't it discriminatory for some UKers to have more triptans, and thus better health care, by the NHS than others solely based on your address?

Left to right – [Guy's](http://www.selondonjointmedicinesformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit=Search),  [Cambridgeshire](http://www.cambridgeshireandpeterboroughformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit=Search), [Salisbury](http://www.bswformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit2=Search), [Oxford](http://www.oxfordhealthformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit2=Search).

[image]

I don't want to cram too many pics in the collage, but [Southampton](http://www.southamptonformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit=Search) has Almotriptan, Sumatriptan and Zolmitriptan, but [Herefordshire](http://www.herefordshireformulary.nhs.uk/searchresults.asp?SearchVar=triptan&Submit2=Search) just the latter two.

Comment: Why would you suppose that it's discriminatory for one area to have different products, and if it is, why would that discrimination be illegal?

Comment: Discrimination isn’t inherently illegal, and some areas of the UK have vastly different healthcare priorities than others, hence the disparity in treatments supplied and funded.  See my answer over in Politics.

Answer (score 1):

### It may be a breach of the [NHS Constitution for England](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-nhs-constitution-for-england/the-nhs-constitution-for-england#patients-and-the-public-your-rights-and-the-nhs-pledges-to-you)

> You have the right to drugs and treatments that have been recommended by NICE for use in the NHS, if your doctor says they are clinically appropriate for you.
>
> You have the right to expect local decisions on funding of other drugs and treatments to be made rationally following a proper consideration of the evidence. If the local NHS decides not to fund a drug or treatment you and your doctor feel would be right for you, they will explain that decision to you.

If the drug has been recommended by [NICE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_for_Health_and_Care_Excellence) then it should be available to you. If it hasn't you should have been told why your local area won't source it for you.